# Cloudify nodecellar: nexpected end of file\ntar:

Tags: cloudify

when I try to install nodecellar with Cloudify,I am getting the following error

> CFY  [nodejs_85efd.create] Task failed 'script_runner.tasks.run' -> RecoverableError('ProcessException: \ngzip: stdin: unexpected end of file\ntar: Unexpected EOF in archive\ntar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now\n\ngzip: stdin: unexpected end of file\ntar: Unexpected EOF in archive\ntar: Unexpected EOF in archive\ntar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now\n',)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this error when the disk is out of space.

If you are installing on a remote machine, SSH into it and and verify that it has enough free space there.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the disk, it  has 11G free space. Nodecellar isn't a big application. So is there any other possibilities?

Comment: 11G is enough. Nodecellar is not a big application, but the mongo packages that the blueprint downloads are unnecessarily large. We would really need to see the complete log output to tell what issues you might be encountering. I don't think that Stack Overflow is the correct forum for full support of your issue. The [Cloudify Users google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloudify-users) will afford a more appropriate support scenario, since it is allowed there to post full log files and other relevant attachments.